# ¿Como importar funciones desde otros archivos .py?

Tags: python, funciones

Tengo el siguiente programa, este funciona,  es acerca de calcular el mayor numero de una lista de n elementos..

```
def llenado_lista():
    respuesta = "y" 
    lista1 = []
    while (respuesta == "y"):
        numero_introducido = int(input("Por favor introduzca un numero: "))
        lista1.append(numero_introducido)
        respuesta = input("Para continuar presiones 'y' y luego enter, de lo 
              contrario presione cualquier tecla: ")

def mayor_todos(lista):
    mayor = lista[0]
    for i in range(1, len(lista)):
        if (lista[i] > mayor):
            mayor = lista[i]

return mayor


new_list1 = llenado_lista()
mayor_all = mayor_todos(new_list1)
print("El mayor de todos los numeros introducidos es", mayor_all)
```

Entonces me surge la siguiente duda, ¿ si quisiera copiar las funciones en otro archivo para solo tener las ultimas 3 lineas de codigo e importar desde otro lado las funciones que cree, como lo haria?
Es decir quiero otro archivo .py en donde tenga las funciones y en otro donde pueda solo importarlas y luego ejecutarlas.

Answer (score 0):

Sólo te faltan unos pequeños pasos para q te funcione, crea otro archivo q este al mismo nivel de este archivo donde tienes las dos funciones que muestras aquí vamos a llamarlo mis_funciones.py para poder entender bien, luego el archivo q vas a crear ponle el  nombre principal.py, ahora dentro de principal pon esta linea, from mis_funciones import llenado_lista, mayor_todos 
Ahora usa estas funciones normalmente. Espero te sirva. Saludos